# In a WinForms custom control, how can a new property change another at design-time?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, custom-controls

I am writing a new custom control based on a TextBox for displaying only numeric values using standard notation, e.g. 12.34e5. I have added a new Value property of decimal type and set it to display in the Properties window in Visual Studio. When the user updates the Value property at design-time, how can I get the Text property to update at the same time? I have seen posts about the DesignMode property - is this the correct path to follow, and if so how?

I realise that NumericUpDown offers numeric display, but it is not suitable for the project requirements.

Comment: Have you tried just setting the `Text` property inside setter of your `Value` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `Text` property of underlying `TextBox` to value you desire.

If you are deriving from `UserControl` class you can do this by setting `Text` property of TextBox you use in your Value setter method like so:

```
public decimal Value
{
    get{ return _value; }
    set
    {
        _value = value;
        textBox1.Text = _value.ToString();
    }
}
```

If you are deriving directly from `TextBox`, just set it's own `Text` property.

```
public decimal Value
{
    get{ return _value; }
    set
    {
        _value = value;
        this.Text = _value.ToString();
    }
}
```